# how to loop a variable in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to loop some variables in the Pine Editor?

If I write a Code (refer to example code) in which I just add a [i] aver the variable the Pine Script Console give me a message error back:

```
//@version=3
strategy("TEEEEST", overlay=true)
tickerID = "ADS"
tickerID1 = "GOOG"
tickerID2 = "FB"
tickerID3 = "AAPL"
tradetimeframe = "60"
vergleichstimeframe = "D"
TaesRSLPeriode = 200
    
        
myEma() => ema(close, TaesRSLPeriode)
Daily_ema = security(tickerID, vergleichstimeframe, myEma())
Hourly_ema1 = security(tickerID1, tradetimeframe, myEma())
Hourly_ema2 = security(tickerID2, tradetimeframe, myEma())
Hourly_ema3 = security(tickerID3, tradetimeframe, myEma())
            
a = 1
for i = 0 to 3
    if a == 1
       if Daily_ema != Hourly_ema[i]
          strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long, 100)
       else 
          strategy.exit("My Long Entry Id")
```

**Message Error : line 26: Undeclared identifier `Hourly_ema`**

Comment: Okay, please tell us where is `Hourly_ema` declared?

Comment: Also, `[]` in pine-script is called [History Referencing Operating](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Operators#History_Referencing_Operator_.28Square_Brackets_.5B.5D.29) and it might not be same as what you think it is.

Comment: Do you mean "Create a set of variables and iterate over them"? If so, then no - arrays (and similar data structures) aren't supported by pine yet.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't declared `Hourly_ema`

I believe you are confusing `Hourly_ema[i]` with `Hourly_ema1`

`Daily_ema[i]` and `Hourly_ema[i]` relate to an array of prior instances of `Daily_ema` and `Hourly_ema`, you have not declared the latter.